# ``apt-mark hold`` and ``apt-mark unhold`` with ansible modules

Tags: ansible, apt

I'm writing my k8s upgrade ansible playbook, and within that I need to do `apt-mark unhold kubeadm`.  Now, I am trying to avoid using the ansible `command` or `shell` module to call `apt` if possible, but the `apt hold/unhold` command does not seem to be supported by neither `package` nor `apt` modules.

Is it possible to do `apt-mark hold` in ansible without `command` or `shell`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the [`ansible.builtin.dpkg_selections` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dpkg_selections_module.html) for this.

*Note that `unhold` translates to `install` in this context.*

```yaml
- name: Hold kubeadm
  ansible.builtin.dpkg_selections:
    name: kubeadm
    selection: hold

- name: Unhold kubeadm
  ansible.builtin.dpkg_selections:
    name: kubeadm
    selection: install
```